Exportar datos masivos de excel a sqlserver
Necesito realizar una exportación de datos masivos de un archivo xlsx a una tabla en sqlserver con laravel 10, mi problema es que no e podido encontrar una forma rapida de poder hacer el insert, tengo entendido que el formato optimo seria mediante un .csv pero el pedido es explicitamente de un xlsx y poder transformalo no fue optimo,
try {
    // Validar el archivo
    $request->validate([
        'archivo' => 'required|file'
    ]);

    // Subir el archivo
    $path = $request->file('archivo')->store('', 'uploads');



    // Obtener la ruta completa del archivo
    $filePath = str_replace('\\', '/', storage_path('app/uploads/' . $path));

    // Ejecutar el comando BULK INSERT en SQL Server
    $sql = "
        BULK INSERT Paso_EFE_C18Consumo
        FROM '{$filePath}'
        WITH (
            FIELDTERMINATOR = ';',
            ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
            FIRSTROW = 2
        )
    ";

    DB::statement($sql);

    return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Archivo subido, leído y procesado correctamente.');
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Ocurrió un error: ' . $e->getMessage());
}

Si alguien sabe alguna forma de poder realizar seria de mucha ayuda o algun consejo

Te recomiendo utilizar la libreria maatwebsite/excel

Ya la use y era muy lenta, use el Chunk y Batch como menciona la documentación pero tarda mucho, el chunk era de 24 de tamaño, si lo aumentaba me da error, cada dato tiene 86 parametros

La instrucción SQL que estás utilizando requiere un archivo de texto plano, por lo que no funcionará con xlsx. Podrías usar SSIS o alguna otra herramienta ETL para transformar los datos e insertar en la tabla.
